apache camel smpp and lazy-start-producer for a TRX connection
I am having an issue where my camel SMPP routes won't start up if any one of the two SMPP servers are not available at the point the spring-boot application is started.
To combat this, I have found the lazy-start-producer option in the configuration (https://camel.apache.org/components/4.4.x/smpp-component.html#_sb_option_camel_component_smpp_lazy-start-producer)
This works great! It now doesn't try to connect until I trigger a message to be sent to the SMS-C; and only at that point will it try and connect - and it will retry instead of killing the application.
However, when the SMS-C starts up, I need the TRX connection to kick back in (I can't use TX and RX as separate connections due to limitations on the SMS-C), so that I can receive messages from the SMS-C even if I haven't tried to send anything yet.
Is there another way I can do this to enable this scenario? Perhaps a timer that can trigger the TRX connection after camel has started up?
I have investigated https://camel.apache.org/manual/route-controller.html#_supervisingroutecontroller but I can't get it to work (see supervisingroutecontroller isn't supervising all routes) - it won't retry the first route, the application just stops after the first failure.
